# is it possible to edit field from listview on long click action?

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to have such functionality in android? When user longclicks row in a list popup window opens with option to edit content?

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. First of all you need to create your own `Dialog` with appropriate xml:

```
private static class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editText;

    public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
        Button btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.getText().toString();//here is your updated(or not updated) text
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

Then add listener at `setOnLongClickListener`:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(this);
listView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        new EditListItemDialog(v.getContext()).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Finally you need to update data in your `ListView`. The right way is to update `Adapter` of your list view which finally will update `ListView`.

Comment: as far as I understand I need to create separate class that extends Dialog and then where do I add this listener?

Comment: Where your `ListView`.

Comment: My ListView is in the java file that returns all data from the table?

Comment: errors say type mismatch: cannot convert from View to Button (TextView)

Comment: @lisoslaw You need to know basics of Java to develop android apps. So I strictly recommend you to read something about `Java`. For instance `Thinking in Java`: http://www.amazon.com/Thinking-Java-Edition-Bruce-Eckel/dp/0131872486/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1397399796&sr=8-1&keywords=thinking+in+java

Comment: I have two books about writing java for android but there is nothing of what I need to do covered...

Comment: it says that constructor ListView is undefined

Comment: can you instruct me how to update Adapter of listview please?

Comment: Can you please have a look at my code and tell me what am I missing here? code does not return any errors but the long click does not take effect and dialog is not launched. I found the Thinking in Java among several other books and I am doing my homework now. Thanks for the reccomendation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to make Dialog file as in your example:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

private View editText;

public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
    View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((TextView) editText).getText().toString();//here is your updated(or not updated) text
    dismiss();
}
}
```

I created an xml file for Dialog file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I updated my Display List file with this code:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(Monday.this);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext()).show();
                return true;

            }
        });
```

And here is full file that displays list of rows to be edited upon Long Click:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cookbook.data.Constants;
import com.cookbook.data.MyDB;




public class Monday extends ListActivity {



private static final int MyMenu = 0;
MyDB dba;
DiaryAdapter myAdapter;

private class MyDiary{
    public MyDiary(String t, String c){
        title=t;
        content=c;




}

    public String title;
    public String content;

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dba = new MyDB(this);
    dba.open();
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_monday);



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(this);
    this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}



private class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<MyDiary> fragment_monday;
    public DiaryAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        fragment_monday = new ArrayList<MyDiary>();
        getdata();
        //new code below
        ListView listView = new ListView(Monday.this);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext()).show();
                return true;

            }
        }); //end of new code
    }

    public void getdata(){
        Cursor c = dba.getdiaries();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String title =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME));
                String content =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME));

                MyDiary temp = new MyDiary(title,content);
                fragment_monday.add(temp);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
        }

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {return fragment_monday.size();}
    public MyDiary getItem(int i) {return fragment_monday.get(i);}
    public long getItemId(int i) {return i;}
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        View v = arg1;
        if ((v == null) || (v.getTag() == null)) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.diaryrow,  null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.mdiary = getItem(arg0);
        holder.mTitle.setText(holder.mdiary.title);


        v.setTag(holder);

        return v;


    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        MyDiary mdiary;
        TextView mTitle;


    }

}




/** Called when the user clicks the Edit button */
public void visitDiary(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Diary.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
/** Called when the user clicks the back button */
public void visitSchedule(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayScheduleScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

There you can see where I put the new code. Unfortunately, upon long click row is not being updated. I mean, the dialog file seems that is not being launched. Is it because I put the code in the wrong place or am I missing something else?